# Convert KB, MB, GB, TB into KB using PERL

Tags: perl

I have the size of disk value as below.

```
323.2T, 123.23G, 1.011T, 2.42M.
```

How to convert all these into KB in Perl

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: See also [`Number::Bytes::Human`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Bytes::Human)

Answer (score 3):

I would build a hash of multipliers for each factor and use it in a regex substitution

The following starts with a multiple of 1 for Kilobytes and increases it my a factor of 1024 == 2<sup>10</sup> for each subsequent factor. You can change 1024 to 1000 == 10<sup>3</sup> if that's what you prefer

The substitution simply looks for a sequence of digits and decimal points followed by one of the eligible factor letters, does the multiplication and replaces the letter with `K`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my %factors;
{
    my $f = 1;

    for my $c ( qw/ K M G T P E / ) {
        $factors{$c} = $f;
        $f *= 1024;
    }
}

my $s = '323.2T, 123.23G, 1.011T, 2.42M';

$s =~ s/([\d.]+)([KMGTPE])/$1 * $factors{$2} . 'K'/eg;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
347033357516.8K, 129216020.48K, 1085552984.064K, 2478.08K
```